# Tracker for UI bugs

Tags: user-interface, bug-tracking, jira, pivotaltracker

I need a tracker, but more specific a tracker for UI issues. An alternative to JIRA o PivotalTracker. I need to post some screenshots, and make annotations on them. I need basically a practical tool for report UI bugs. Anny suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there reasons you are not using JIRA and PivotalTracker? That might guide other people to assist you better when offering tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also have a look at JIRA in combination with the screen-sniper plugin
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/19613

Answer (score 0):

Almost all tools allow you to attach files.  Many show graphics files in-line.  Choose any of those.